# Howto set "stop the existing instance" with win_scheduled_task?

Tags: ansible, task, scheduler

I am creating Windows Task Scheduler tasks with the respective Ansible module. On the Windows Task Scheduler frontend I can set a value "stop the existing instance" for "If the task is already running, the following rule applies:".

How can I set that via the Ansible module? It seems to be necessary for my task.

[image]